# Is there a way to get Shift (or Ctrl / alt) key status on Android emulator?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm currently trying to read special key status from a Bluetooth Keyboard.
It works as expected on real device.

But on emulator, it seems it's not possible.
On keyup/keydown handlers only make it possible through getMetaState but you need to press another valid key to get it.

So how to read Shift / Alt / Ctrl on the hard keyboard on Android Emulator ?